# Retrieve sid from registry for a logged out user

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I want to list all the users on a PC, and I can do that by listing all the subkeys under the HKEY_USERS registry. But I encountered a problem. If a user has logged out then the sid won't be shown.
Any hints on how can I retrieve that sid of a logged out user?
P.S.: My app is run by an Admin, and I don't know the users, or their profile names, or passwords. So, keep that in mind.

Comment: Read the registry is the wrong way to solve the problem. You are trying to enumerate user accounts on the machine. I've shown one duplicate question but there are many more. Rather than asking about your solution (which doesn't solve your problem in fact) it is better to ask about your problem.

Comment: I want to delete a particular registry key for all the users on a PC. That's why I need the Sids, to know which is the subkey for every user

Answer (score 0):

You can start by enumerating users with `NetUserEnum` (as shown in the question that was previously nominated as a duplicate).

That won't get you the SID for each user though. The closest it can get you is a RID for each user.

One way to get the SID for each user enumerated is to user `NetUserGetInfo`, giving it the user name returned by `NetUserEnum`:

```
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>
#include <lmaccess.h>
#include <lmapibuf.h>
#include <Sddl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")

int main(void) {

    USER_INFO_0 *buffer;
    DWORD entries;
    DWORD total_entries;
    DWORD resume_handle = 0;

    do { 
        NetUserEnum(NULL, 
            0,
            FILTER_NORMAL_ACCOUNT, 
            (BYTE **)&buffer, 
            4096, 
            &entries, 
            &total_entries, 
            &resume_handle);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < entries; i++) {
            USER_INFO_23 *info;
            NetUserGetInfo(NULL, buffer[i].usri0_name, 23, (LPBYTE *)&info);
            LPTSTR string_sid;
            ConvertSidToStringSid(info->usri23_user_sid, &string_sid);
            printf("%-20.20S\t%s\n", buffer[i].usri0_name, string_sid);
            NetApiBufferFree(info);
        }    
        NetApiBufferFree(buffer);    
    } while ( resume_handle != 0);
}
```

But, although the duplicate he nominated didn't (quite) answer your question, I agree with David Heffernan that this probably isn't a good approach to solve the problem you're having.